# iOS crash on mapview CGLocation

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I had this crash occurs while testing the map using Xcode 4.3.2; targeting iOS 5.1, below is the backtrace :

```
(lldb) bt all

* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x026edcaa libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, stop reason = breakpoint 1.3
frame #0: 0x026edcaa libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x029da644 CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 196
frame #2: 0x000f21fb SubwayDA`-[LocationsMapSubviewController mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:] + 699 at LocationsMapSubviewController.m:174
frame #3: 0x00073b27 SubwayDA`-[CalloutMapAnnotationView calloutAccessoryTapped:] + 263 at CalloutMapAnnotationView.m:382
frame #4: 0x029efe99 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 73
frame #5: 0x00f1514e UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
frame #6: 0x00f150e6 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
frame #7: 0x00fbbade UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
frame #8: 0x00fbbfa7 UIKit`-[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503
frame #9: 0x00fba1f8 UIKit`-[UIControl cancelTrackingWithEvent:] + 142
frame #10: 0x00fba0b9 UIKit`-[UIControl cancelTouchTracking] + 65
frame #11: 0x00fbb47b UIKit`-[UIControl _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 109
frame #12: 0x00f4dedb UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 479
frame #13: 0x00f4a692 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 158
frame #14: 0x00f48ee6 UIKit`__UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 140
frame #15: 0x00f48b61 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 176
frame #16: 0x00caaa83 MapKit`MKLongHash + 38425
frame #17: 0x00caa91c MapKit`MKLongHash + 38066
frame #18: 0x00caa620 MapKit`MKLongHash + 37302
frame #19: 0x00caa6b5 MapKit`MKLongHash + 37451
frame #20: 0x00c98370 MapKit
frame #21: 0x000f3615 SubwayDA`-[LocationsMapSubviewController updateMapWithSpan:centered:] + 293 at LocationsMapSubviewController.m:304
frame #22: 0x000f9f5e SubwayDA`-[LocationsViewController DidFCPositionUpdateFinished] + 94 at LocationsViewController.m:570
frame #23: 0x029efdea CoreFoundation`-[NSObject performSelector:] + 58
frame #24: 0x00080904 SubwayDA`-[ModelDataServerSynchronizer callSuccesfulDelegate] + 228 at ModelDataServerSynchronizer.m:1031
frame #25: 0x000807f6 SubwayDA`-[ModelDataServerSynchronizer CallDelegates] + 134 at ModelDataServerSynchronizer.m:1015
frame #26: 0x0007b12f SubwayDA`-[ModelDataServerSynchronizer DidUpdateAllFCPositions:] + 751 at ModelDataServerSynchronizer.m:542
frame #27: 0x00079e1d SubwayDA`-[ModelDataServerSynchronizer requestFinished:] + 429 at ModelDataServerSynchronizer.m:346
frame #28: 0x029efe42 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 66
frame #29: 0x0008b8f6 SubwayDA`-[RestDataService requestFinished:] + 1766 at RestDataService.m:350
frame #30: 0x029efe42 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 66
frame #31: 0x00031eeb SubwayDA`-[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] + 171 at ASIHTTPRequest.m:2019
frame #32: 0x029efe42 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 66
frame #33: 0x018389df Foundation`__NSThreadPerformPerform + 254
frame #34: 0x029c294f CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
frame #35: 0x02925b43 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
frame #36: 0x02925424 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1012
frame #37: 0x02924d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #38: 0x02924c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #39: 0x02df17d8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 190
frame #40: 0x02df188a GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 103
frame #41: 0x00f12626 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1163
frame #42: 0x0000269d SubwayDA`main + 125 at main.m:12

thread #3: tid = 0x2403, 0x980b990a libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent + 10
frame #0: 0x980b990a libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent + 10
frame #1: 0x02d97372 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 918
frame #2: 0x02d95be1 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 53

thread #5: tid = 0x2603, 0x980b6c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #0: 0x980b6c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #1: 0x980b61f6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 70
frame #2: 0x029c210a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
frame #3: 0x029255d5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1445
frame #4: 0x02924d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #5: 0x02924c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #6: 0x06ef9420 WebCore`_ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 560
frame #7: 0x9b2c3ed9 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 335

thread #9: tid = 0x2a03, 0x980b6c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #0: 0x980b6c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #1: 0x980b61f6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 70
frame #2: 0x029c210a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
frame #3: 0x029255d5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1445
frame #4: 0x02924d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #5: 0x02924c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #6: 0x01912e30 Foundation`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 398
frame #7: 0x018244d6 Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
frame #8: 0x01824447 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1258
frame #9: 0x9b2c3ed9 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 335

thread #10: tid = 0x2b03, 0x980b902e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
frame #0: 0x980b902e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
frame #1: 0x9b2c5ccf libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 773

thread #13: tid = 0x2e03, 0x980b902e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
frame #0: 0x980b902e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
frame #1: 0x9b2c5ccf libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 773

thread #14: tid = 0x2f03, 0x980b8b42 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
frame #0: 0x980b8b42 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
frame #1: 0x029567cb CoreFoundation`__CFSocketManager + 939
frame #2: 0x9b2c3ed9 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 335

thread #15: tid = 0x3003, 0x980b6c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #0: 0x980b6c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #1: 0x980b61f6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 70
frame #2: 0x029c210a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
frame #3: 0x029255d5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1445
frame #4: 0x02924d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #5: 0x02926e81 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRun + 129
frame #6: 0x000416ef SubwayDA`+[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] + 223 at ASIHTTPRequest.m:4793
frame #7: 0x018244d6 Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
frame #8: 0x01824447 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1258
frame #9: 0x9b2c3ed9 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 335

thread #16: tid = 0x3103, 0x980b6c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #0: 0x980b6c22 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
frame #1: 0x980b61f6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 70
frame #2: 0x029c210a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 186
frame #3: 0x029255d5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1445
frame #4: 0x02924d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #5: 0x02924c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #6: 0x00ca086b MapKit`MKNormalizedPointForLayer + 30057
frame #7: 0x018244d6 Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
frame #8: 0x01824447 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1258
frame #9: 0x9b2c3ed9 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 335

thread #17: tid = 0x3203, 0x980b6c76 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
frame #0: 0x980b6c76 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
frame #1: 0x02d990ad libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 247
frame #2: 0x02d990fa libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_semaphore_wait + 36
frame #3: 0x0080bac3 CoreLocation`CLClientInvokeCallback(__CLClient*, CLClientEvent, __CFDictionary const*) + 469
frame #4: 0x0080de18 CoreLocation`___CLClientCreateConnection_block_invoke_0 + 307
frame #5: 0x0084183d CoreLocation`__setDefaultMessageHandler_onQueue_block_invoke_0 + 76
frame #6: 0x0083ef01 CoreLocation`CLConnection::handleMessage(CLConnectionMessage*) + 75
frame #7: 0x0083eeb1 CoreLocation`__initializeConnection_nl_block_invoke_0 + 27
frame #8: 0x0083fc07 CoreLocation`__setEventHandler_block_invoke_0 + 286
frame #9: 0x02db4c84 libxpc.dylib`__XPC_CONNECTION_EVENT_HANDLER_CALLOUT__ + 52
frame #10: 0x02db70e3 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_connection_recv_message + 650
frame #11: 0x02db7b87 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_connection_wakeup_recv + 199
frame #12: 0x02db7a2e libxpc.dylib`_xpc_connection_wakeup2 + 1598
frame #13: 0x02db7c59 libxpc.dylib`_xpc_connection_wakeup + 101
frame #14: 0x02d9a450 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_invoke + 719
frame #15: 0x02d96cc4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 66
frame #16: 0x02d96e50 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 272
frame #17: 0x02d96cb4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 50
frame #18: 0x02d96e50 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 272
frame #19: 0x02d96cb4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 50
frame #20: 0x02d96e50 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 272
frame #21: 0x02d96cb4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 50
frame #22: 0x02d96402 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 247
frame #23: 0x9b2c5b24 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 346

thread #18: tid = 0x3303, 0x980b902e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
frame #0: 0x980b902e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
frame #1: 0x9b2c5ccf libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 773

thread #19: tid = 0x3403, 0x980b902e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
frame #0: 0x980b902e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
frame #1: 0x9b2c5ccf libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 773
```

(lldb)

any help to trace it or clue on what is on going on would be appreciated ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Were going to need some code, particularly around the breakpoint where it crashed. To enable that, on the file sidebar, press the breakpoint tab and then press + on the button and select "On Throw" and make sure it is on all exceptions and add it

Comment: Are you using a xib/storyboard for your mapview?

Comment: I'm using xib including mapview, I have been posted details on another thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205051/altering-the-mkmapview-removing-annotations